# Header showing up in every page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create pdf using DOMpdf. The following script is what I am trying to create the pdf of and when I get the pdf it looks like the image I have posted below:(please check)

Now my problem is the header is showing up in every single page and the texts of my content are going through the footer section. I just want to have the header in the first page and page numbers in the position of footers in every page. I have been messing up with it for almost 24hrs but still couldn't make it happen.

Would you please kindly help me solve this problem?

Thanks in Advance

```
 <html>
 <head>

 <style>
    @page {
   size: auto;   /* auto is the initial value */
   margin: 10%;
 }

#header { position: fixed; left: 0px; top: -100px; right: 0px; height: 120px; background-color: orange; text-align: center; }
#footer { position: fixed; left: 0px; bottom: -180px; right: 0px; height: 150px; background-color: white; }
#footer .page:after { content: counter(page, upper-roman); }
#content{height:600px;}

</style>

 <body>

 <div id=\"header\">
 <h1>Widgets Express</h1>
</div>
 <div id=\"footer\">
<p class=\"page\">Page </p>
 </div>


<div id=\"content\">


<table style=\"table-layout:fixed;width:600px;\">
<tr height=\"30\">
<td width=\"150\">CSS table layout cell 1</td>
<td width=\"200\">CSS table layout cell 2</td>
<td width=\"250\">CSS table layout cell 3</td>

 </tr>


 </table>


 <p style=\"page-break-before: always;\">the second page</p>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you have backslashes all over your quotes?

Comment: Thanks BoltClock for your reply. I should have mentioned it before... actually I am writing the above code inside a PHP tag that's why I have backslashes all over my quotes. I am putting all these code inside a php variable to create PDF. thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the header, use:

```
#header { position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; height: 120px; }
body { padding-top: 120px; }
```

As for the pagination, I am not quite sure if that can be done like this in css this straight forward.

edit:

changing the header and footer script will work:

```
#header { position: absolute; left: 0; top: -100px; right: 0; height: 100px;background-color: orange; text-align: center;  }

 #footer {position: fixed ; left: 0px; bottom: -110px; right: 0px; height: 40px; background-color: orange; }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot kontur. I tired position: absolute and then changed the top to-> top:-100 and now got rid of the header but still text of my contents going through my footer. (Please check the first arrow in the image I posted above.)  Do you have any solution to this? thanks :)

Comment: hi, I have got the solution. I changed my footer CSS with this-  #footer {position: fixed ; left: 0px; bottom: -110px; right: 0px; height: 40px; background-color: orange; } and it is working perfectly now. :)

Comment: alrighties, glad to have been of help. The top: -100px does the same thing, just pushing the header outward instead of the contents inward - should be fine as long as you have enough space around the page ,)

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because you are using 'position: fixed' for your header and footer

Comment: thanks for your reply. I tried absolute but the contents in the first page goes inside the header and in the second page the contents start from middle position.. Could you please tell me how to get rid of this problem? Thanks :)

Comment: If you remove the position rule, and stick to the default static position , it should solve your problem. But, not sure how you will handle paginantion #header {height: 120px; background-color: orange; text-align: center; }
#footer {height: 150px; background-color: white; }